# How to create JSON data inside a loop using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, json

I need to create JSON data inside a loop using Ruby code (Ruby only not Rails).

I need the code exactly as below,

```
for i in 0..2
   jsondata = {:aaa => 1.4, :bbb => 0.89, :ccc => 0.6, :ddd => 1.3}
end

final jsondata = [{:aaa => 1.4, :bbb => 0.89, :ccc => 0.6, :ddd => 1.3}, {:aaa => 1.4,
:bbb => 0.89, :ccc => 0.6, :ddd => 1.3}, {:aaa => 1.4, :bbb => 0.89, :ccc => 0.6, :ddd 
=> 1.3}] (3 times loop. Not unique data everytime different data)
```

final **jsondata** should contain all the jsondata run on the loop. It is the final JSON data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ruby's built-in JSON library and an Array to do this:

```
require 'json'
entries = []

entries = (0..2).map |i|
  {:aaa => 1.4, :bbb => 0.89, :ccc => 0.6, :ddd => 1.3}
end

p entries
# => [{:aaa=>1.4, :bbb=>0.89, :ccc=>0.6, :ddd=>1.3}, {:aaa=>1.4, :bbb=>0.89, :ccc=>0.6, :ddd=>1.3}, {:aaa=>1.4, :bbb=>0.89, :ccc=>0.6, :ddd=>1.3}]

p entries.to_json
# => "[{\"aaa\":1.4,\"bbb\":0.89,\"ccc\":0.6,\"ddd\":1.3},{\"aaa\":1.4,\"bbb\":0.89,\"ccc\":0.6,\"ddd\":1.3},{\"aaa\":1.4,\"bbb\":0.89,\"ccc\":0.6,\"ddd\":1.3}]"
```

Note: If you just need an array of Hashes and not an actual JSON string, you can get rid of the `require 'json'`.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little confusing, so I'm not sure what you're hoping to accomplish, but something like this should work:

```
data = (0..2).map do |i|
  { :a => i, :b => (i+1) }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't exactly clear, but this will do exactly what you asked:

```
require 'json'

json_data = 3.times.map { {:aaa => 1.4, :bbb => 0.89, :ccc => 0.6, :ddd => 1.3} }
json_data.to_json

=> "[{\"aaa\":1.4,\"bbb\":0.89,\"ccc\":0.6,\"ddd\":1.3},{\"aaa\":1.4,\"bbb\":0.89,\"ccc\":0.6,\"ddd\":1.3},{\"aaa\":1.4,\"bbb\":0.89,\"ccc\":0.6,\"ddd\":1.3}]"
```